# Migrate large WordPress site

Tags: php, wordpress

I need to export the current WordPress website data to my local machine. I know how to do this but i have a small problem and that's about the large amount of images in the `wp-content` folder. I only want to have the original images so i can generate the new sizes myself. Is there a good way to export and import the `wp-conten` files without all the extra image sizes?

At this point when i do a export from the current website is doesn't include all the images when i import these and i get a lot of broken images.

Comment: Try this plugin - https://wordpress.org/plugins/all-in-one-wp-migration/

Comment: Have a look at https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-attachment-export/